# Find all web servers in the repository

Tags: debian, package-management

I need to find all the web servers available from the repository for an ARM-based Debian appliance.

I ran the following, but it returns too many hits (including libraries, etc.):

```
apt-get update
apt-cache search http server
```

Is there a better command that I should use instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$ aptitude show httpd
```

`httpd` is a virtual package provided by a lot of web server packages. On my Ubuntu 13.10 box, I get:

```
No current or candidate version found for httpd
Package: httpd
State: not a real package
Provided by: aolserver4-core, aolserver4-daemon, apache2-bin, boa, bozohttpd, ebhttpd,
         lighttpd, micro-httpd, mini-httpd, nginx-extras, nginx-full, nginx-light,
         nginx-naxsi, nginx-naxsi-ui, ocsigenserver, tntnet, webfs, yaws
```